# Sharepoint Framework - custom webpart @ Sharepoint Online - app refers to localhost

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-framework

I need to create a simple app using **Sharepoint Framework - app** will generate iframe with body taken from external vendor. Normally in regular HTML website I would just put  tag in the head section but here I just put this script code in the render method in TS file of this new module. Anyway, locally it works absolutely fine, works as expected.

Then it came to bundle it to a single piece. 
I ran gulp bundle and gulp package-solution to build the app.

*Now when my Client tries to upload the app by uploading JS file, he see reference to localhost:4321 and entire upload crashes:*

> Failed to load URL 'https://localhost:4321/lib/webparts...'

I see this has something to do with manifest file but what exactly I should change over there? Does it mean I have to upload it to CDN or what (or maybe another free of charge source)? I thought once it's build it's fully independent as everything needed is inside single file - and that's why you want to upload it - to make it working from this source.

Sorry if this is dummy question but never played with SF before

Answer (score 3):

You need to run `gulp bundle` and `gulp package-solution` with `--ship` flag to get a production version of the package.

`gulp bundle --ship`

`gulp package-solution --ship`

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy to a document library, you can check the demo shared by Nanddeep Nachan.

[image]

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-framework-deploy-spfx-webparts-to-sharepoint-library/